# Why does batch set variables loaded from a file to 0?

Tags: batch-file

I recently started to play around batch again. And tried to make a password protected function.

I'm loading username and password from a `.txt` file so I can compare the user input with the pre-loaded variables. The problem is that somewhere between the loading and checking if there are the same, they are converted to 0.

Here is some code

```
@echo off
:login
cd /
cd C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\account
set /P Pname=<Account_Name.txt
rem P = preloaded
set /P Ppassword=<Account_Password.txt
title login
cls
date /t
timeout /t 2>nul
cls
echo please type your username
set /P _name=here:
echo enter password
set /P _pass=here:
if "%_name%" == "%Pname%" goto chck1

:chck1
if "%_pass%" == "%Ppassword%" goto ms (

else goto iclogin
)
```

In the ms function i just print hello world!

In the iclogin function i print that the password or username are incorrect

Edit: when I do `echo %Pname%` and `echo %Ppassword%` it says "Echo is off" - I placed it right after the load from the file

Comment: you might want to explain what is converted to 0 (it is unclear) and to show what makes you believe they are converted to 0.  (By inserting statements in the code, and then showing the exact output of the program.)  Also: does it make a difference if you use `set Pname=foo` instead of `set /P Pname=<Account_Name.txt` ?  If yes, then this does not work.  If not, we would rather not be bothered with `set /P Pname=<Account_Name.txt` while looking at your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to post a re-write of your script, because you really should make your code more robust, especially when end users, *(read as imbeciles)* are providing input.

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

:Login
CD /D "%UserProfile%\Desktop\account" 2> NUL || GoTo :EOF
For %%G In (Name Password) Do (
    If Exist "Account_%%G.txt" (
        Set "Preset%%G="
        Set /P "Preset%%G=" 0< "Account_%%G.txt"
    ) Else GoTo :EOF) 
For %%G in (Name Password) Do If Not Defined Preset%%G GoTo :EOF
Title LogIn
ClS
Date /T
"%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" /T 2 1> NUL
ClS
For %%G In (name pass) Do Set "_%%G="
Set /P "_name=Please type your username here>"
(Set _name | "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /IR "^_name=%PresetName%$") 1> NUL 2>&1
If ErrorLevel 1 GoTo ICLogIn
Set /P "_pass=Please enter your password here>"
(Set _pass | "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /IR "^_pass=%PresetPassword%$") 1> NUL 2>&1
If Not ErrorLevel 1 GoTo MS
Echo Login Failed
Echo Press any key to close. . .
"%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" /T -1 1> NUL
GoTo :EOF

:ICLogin
Echo Create a LogIn
Timeout /T 3
GoTo :EOF

:MS
Echo Passed
Timeout /T 3
```

*I've just placed some basic messages beneath the `:MS` and `:ICLogin` labels, just to keep the code standalone complete. You would obviously propagate those areas with your own code as needed. Please do not change anything whatsoever before testing it, I'm not supporting your modifications.*